Как получать данные с ардуино на python 3.11?
Как получать данные с ардуино на python? Я вывожу данные с потенциометра на com порт и всё отображается в просмотре порта программы Arduino IDE, но в пайтоне - нет. Я использую pycharm и python 3.11 и пробовал запускать в консоли. Я пробовал уже много разных кодов, вот один из них:
import serial
ser=serial.Serial(port='COM7', baudrate=9600)
while True:
  line = ser.readline()
  print (line)

Я ожидал что будут данные в виде чисел, но консоль вообще пустая, даже нет ошибок

А вы уверены, что там строки приходят с EOL на конце? Попробуйте просто побайтовый ser.read() для начала. Ну и номер порта проверить и прочие параметры, коих там вагон можно разных задать, а здесь они по умолчанию, ибо не указаны.

Побайтово получает, но по 1 букве, а как получать срузу строкой?

Ну через chr(line) получайте символы и сами соберите их в строку. Что-то известно - сколько символов ожидается, например? Или может какие-то разделители есть? Перевод строки не приходит, поэтому на строку именно нельзя ориентироваться, похоже. Покажите, что вы видите там другой программой, какую строку?

Как вариант, можете задать в Serial таймаут, например timeout=1 и тогда вернётся что сможет за это время прочитаться через readline. Или даже timeout=0, если данные уже точно есть в порту и их не нужно ждать. Так конечно проще будет, чем самому строку из символов собирать.

Нет символов которые известны

Ну с заданием таймаута попробуйте deadline
